# Cargo build fails ld: library not found for -lmcrypt on Apple sillicon

Tags: rust, ld, mcrypt

I have installed `mcrypt` on my apple m1 chip using a `brew` and `pecl`

```
$ which mcrypt
/opt/homebrew/bin/mcrypt

$ pecl list
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package Version State
mcrypt  1.0.4   stable
```

However, when I build my personal Rust project locally, it fails to link libraries as follows. Is there some configuration that I am doing wrong or is there a parameter that I need to specify during the build?

```
= note: ld: library not found for -lmcrypt
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Cargo version**

```
cargo -V
cargo 1.60.0 (d1fd9fe2c 2022-03-01)
```

**ld -v**

```
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-762
BUILD 06:28:58 Feb 18 2022
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 13.1.6, (clang-1316.0.21.2) (static support for 28, runtime is 28)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 13.1.6 (tapi-1316.0.7.3)
```

**sw_vers**

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.3.1
BuildVersion:   21E258
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue.
Just needed to export the `$LIBRARY_PATH` explicitly by typing:

```sh
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/mcrypt/lib/
```

Comment: Pretty crazy, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, RUSTFLAGS all failed for me until I did this variation.  The library was in a known custom path, I just didn't know how to tell rust (cc) about it.